# Convolve two sets of (x,y) data sets

Tags: list-manipulation, signal-processing, convolution

I have two sets of data in the form

```
a={{.1,2},{.2,3},{.3,4},{.5,6}}

b={{0,8},{.1,4},{.2,7},{.3,1},{.5,10},{.6,3}}
```

Both data sets have even spacing, although the `b` dataset has significantly many more data points at higher and lower values of `x`. How do I convolve these data sets?

`Convolve[a,b]` only works if I use just the `y` values of the datasets. Is there a way to convolve this data while still keeping these `x` values?

Comment: `Convolve` doesn't work at all.  It's for symbolic convolution.  `ListConvolve` works, but you can't keep the `x` values.  You'll need to re-add them afterwards.

Comment: Your data sets don't have values at .4... the data needs to be defined at all times in a regularly spaced intervals in order for convolution to be defined.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Yes I am using ListConvolve, and the data I have written there is just an example. My actual data sets are several hundred thousand points. I will try adding the x coordinates back into my ListConvolved data set.

Answer (score 2):

If you used [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html), as mentioned by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42644/convolve-two-sets-of-x-y-data-sets#comment127536_42644), you could get the following solutions.

```
a = {{.1, 2}, {.2, 3}, {.3, 4}, {.5, 6}};
b = {{0, 8}, {.1, 4}, {.2, 7}, {.3, 1}, {.5, 10}, {.6, 3}};
ListConvolve[a, b]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  8.3 \\
>  8.6 \\
>  11.2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Or

```
Table[ListConvolve[a, b, #], 1] & /@ Range[4]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  71.42 & 10.5 \\
>  104.44 & 13.5 \\
>  76.34 & 9.7 \\
>  87.1 & 8.3 \\
>  75.22 & 8.6 \\
>  82.35 & 11.2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  13.5 & 104.44 \\
>  9.7 & 76.34 \\
>  8.3 & 87.1 \\
>  8.6 & 75.22 \\
>  11.2 & 82.35 \\
>  10.5 & 71.42 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  76.34 & 9.7 \\
>  87.1 & 8.3 \\
>  75.22 & 8.6 \\
>  82.35 & 11.2 \\
>  71.42 & 10.5 \\
>  104.44 & 13.5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  8.3 & 87.1 \\
>  8.6 & 75.22 \\
>  11.2 & 82.35 \\
>  10.5 & 71.42 \\
>  13.5 & 104.44 \\
>  9.7 & 76.34 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$